# How to get from month as number the short abbreviation for the month?

Tags: windows, batch-file, set

I have a script running on 3 servers in various locations which moves JPGs to a folder each night using the `YYYY MM DD`, i.e. images captured today will be moved at 23:55 to a folder called 2014, a subfolder called 12, and a further subfolder called 31.

However, I want to set the month as **Dec** not **12**.

The script I am using is:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

e:
cd \webcam\webadminpan

ECHO Checking For any JPG Files
DIR /b *.jpg > NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO NoFilesFound
ECHO Found Files To Move

SET thisyear=%date:~6,4%
echo I am this year : %thisyear%
SET thismonth=%date:~3,2%
echo I am this month : %thismonth%
SET thisday=%date:~0,2%
echo I am this day : %thisday%

:CheckYearCreate
ECHO Checking to see if year directory %thisyear% exists 
DIR /b "%thisyear%"> NUL 2>&1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CreateYear 
ECHO Directory %thisyear% must already be present

:CheckMonthCreate
ECHO Checking to see if month directory %thismonth% exists 
DIR /b "%thisyear%\%thismonth%"> NUL 2>&1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CreateMonth 
ECHO Directory %thisyear%/%thismonth% must already be present

:CheckDayCreate
ECHO Checking to see if day directory %thisday% exists 
DIR /b "%thisyear%\%thismonth%\%thisday%"> NUL 2>&1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CreateDay 
ECHO Directory %thisyear%/%thismonth%/%thisday% must already be present

:MoveJPGFiles
ECHO Moving JPG Files To "%thisyear%/%thismonth%/%thisday%"
MOVE *.jpg "%thisyear%\%thismonth%\%thisday%"
GOTO TheEnd


:CreateYear
ECHO Making Year %thisyear% Directory
MKDIR "e:\webcam\webadminpan\%thisyear%"
GOTO CheckYearCreate

:CreateMonth
ECHO Making Month %thismonth% Directory
MKDIR "e:\webcam\webadminpan\%thisyear%\%thismonth%"
GOTO CheckMonthCreate

:CreateDay
ECHO Making Day %thisday% Directory
MKDIR "e:\webcam\webadminpan\%thisyear%\%thismonth%\%thisday%"
GOTO CheckDayCreate

:NoFilesFound
ECHO Nothing to Move

:TheEnd
ECHO Finished

Exit /b 0
```

Can anyone advise on how I can accomplish this and get `thismonth` set with short abbreviation instead of number?

Answer (score 0):

Try this after `thismonth` is initialized:

```
:: assuming that thismonth is already set by your script.
set thismonth=09

:: clears the leading zeroes
cmd /c exit /b %thismonth%
set c_month=%errorlevel%

:: sets month as a word but not as a digits
for /f "tokens=%c_month%" %%a in ("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec") do set "w_month=%%a"

:: month is set as a word
echo %w_month%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR %%a IN ("01 Jan" "02 Feb" "06 Jun" "07 Jul") DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%b IN (%%a) DO IF %month%==%%b SET "month=%%c"
```

Assuming your `month` has a leading zero - remove leading zeroes if this is not so. The code replaces the numeric value in `month` with the text.

BTW - You can `MKDIR` a directory (or `MD` - it's a synonym) and simply append `2>nul` to the line to suppress the 'directory already exists' message. That would save you a heap of code...